# Why apache does not look for assets in the current project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache

I just installed apache and i'm running a simple project but something weird is happening. Apache try to look for assets in the wrong place, let's take an image for example. Apache goes to "localhost/images/IMAGE_NAME" instead of "localhost/PROJECT_NAME/images/IMAGE_NAME". How can i configure it so it look for assets in the right place ?.
this is my index page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>BlackBird Co.</title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
 <header class="bird-box">
   <div class="back-bird"></div>
   <div class="logo"></div>
   <div class="fore-bird"></div>
 </header>
 <section class="content">
   <article>
     <h1>Clothing Store</h1>
     <hr>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa.</p>
     <hr>
   </article>
   <div style="height: 2000px"></div>
 </section>
 <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Inserting your code with the question would be helpful @TyLO

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for your interest !  I want to play around with Parallax so i just cloned this code there https://github.com/DevTips/Parallax-on-the-Web-DevTips-/releases/tag/v0.1

Comment: your code...where you're trying to include the image

Comment: I edited my answer, it might help you ^^

Comment: Hi! I'm just guessing, but are your image paths "/images/IMAGE_NAME"? try changing them to simply "images/IMAGE_NAME" :) (No slash at start)

Comment: Thanks Sam that was it ! put it as the answer if you can !  Thats was too obvious i guess x)

Comment: Hi, I'll add it as an answer in case anybody comes across a similar issue in the future. Good luck with your future programming endeavors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So (As was mentioned in the OP's comments), the issue here was with the path names beginning with a slash (i.e. "/images/IMAGE_NAME" instead of "images/IMAGE_NAME").

When on linux box, beginning with a slash indicates an absolute path rather than a relative one. It can be an annoying but common error to make, so if your filenames aren't resolving, it's a good place to start looking! It's usually the little things...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your HTML file is in the "localhost/PROJECT_NAME" folder. If it's not (i.e. maybe it's in the parent folder), that would explain why you're having the issue, and to fix it you would need to either move your HTML file into PROJECT_NAME, add PROJECT_NAME to all your URLs, or move the asset folders out of PROJECT_NAME.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my index file is inside my project and i dont really want to move the assets out of the project they belong.